# C++ derived class assignment operator

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, operator-keyword, derived

I was reading C++ Primer chapter 13 "Class Inheritance", something about assignment operator in derived class confuse me. Here is the case:
In base class:

```
class baseDMA
{
  private:
      char * label;// label will point to dynamic allocated space(use new)
      int rating;
  public:
      baseDMA & operator=(const baseDMA & rs);
      //remaining declaration...

};
//implementation
baseDMA & baseDMA::operator=(const baseDMA & rs)
{
      if(this == &rs)
      {
          return *this;
      }
      delete [] label;
      label = new char[std::strlen(rs.label) + 1];
      std::strcpy(label,rs.label);
      rating = rs.rating;
      return *this;
}
// remaining implementation
```

In derived class

```
class hasDMA : public baseDMA
{
    private:
        char * style;// additional pointer in derived class 
    public:
        hasDMA & operator=(const hasDMA& rs);
        //remaining declaration...
};
// implementation
hasDMA & hasDMA::operator=(const hasDMA & hs)
{
    if(this == &hs)
        return *this;
    baseDMA::operator=(hs);
    style = new char[std::strlen(hs.style) + 1];
    std::strcpy(style, hs.style);
    return *this;
}
// remaining implementation
```

my question is: in derived class assignment operator definition , why do not need to delete the style first(like delete label in baseDMA) before allocated new spaces to it?

Thank you.

Comment: You _do_ need to delete it otherwise you end up leaking memory.

Answer (score 0):

At that point `style` has a pointer yo set up from previous call to new char[]. If you assign to it, you lose the last chance to call the delete[], and create a memory leak.

As an important note, treat the code you show just as a demonstration of a concept. Normally you're not supposed to do such things directly, but having a member that specializes in the task, and the outer class needs no dtor or op= at all. Like for your example label and style could be std::string and the only dtor and op= that requires hand-crafring is that of std::string!